# How to Print Unicode (Bangla Font) to Thermal Printer in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, thermal-printer

In my current flutter project I need print bangla language (Bangladeshi). I'm using [blue thermal printer](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer). Here is output of my print in attached picture [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3N3Y.jpg).

Comment: Please show the source code of what kind of program it is, and add information such as the printer's Vader/model and the device and OS it is running. For example, the printer would have to support printing in Bangladesh.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.